# How to find out if a substring of a Java string matches a regular expression?

Tags: java, grep

The Java String class has a matches(String regex) method that checks whether the current string matches the given regular expression. However, how can we find whether a substring of the current string would match the regular expression?

I am trying to mimic the behavior of grep using Java. grep takes a line and prints all those lines that match the given regular expression anywhere in the line. I am not sure how to do that with Java, because the matches method checks whether the entire line (i.e. string) matches the regex and not any substring within it.

Comment: Would putting wildcards on both ends of the regex solve your problem?

Comment: Wow @ColinD , that's an awesome suggestion! It would definitely solve my problem!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like ColinD said, your best bet is to read in your strings a line at a time, then run your regex with a reluctant wildcard on both ends.

Comment: So you copied Colin's comment and made it your answer!? Lol

Comment: No, since you have to make sure the wildcards are reluctant or it won't work and he didn't specify.

Comment: There are 2 important types of wildcard operators, greedy and reluctant. Edit: Accidentally hit enter early, give me a sec to finish typing.

Greedy wildcards will grab as many matches as then can, and only allow the minimum left over for the rest of the regex. For example, if your regex was .*[a].*, which is using greedy operators, it would **not** match the string "ab", because the greedy operator would grab the first character 'a' and leave one last character, because that's all [a] needs to check against. so the check for [a] would fail, as it's checking against 'b'.

Comment: To fix this, you need to check against a reluctant wildcard, which grabs as few characters as possible. so if you use that same regex, but with a reluctant, it would first try grabbing 0, then the [a] portion would check and pass, then the second wildcard would grab the b, you'd pass. There's a good writeup here: http://javamex.com/tutorials/regular_expressions/repetition_greedy_reluctant.shtml

Comment: I tried this. It seems that Java regexes are non-greedy by default.

Comment: Regexs aren't greedy, operators are. The default wildcard operator: ".*" is greedy. The reluctant version is ".*?"

Answer (score 6):

The `Matcher#find()` method does what you want

Comment: how do you get the match found? find returns a boolean

Answer (score 1):

You can modify the regular expression to allow wildcards at the front and back of the string.

So instead of:

```
Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("hello\\sworld")
```

you have

```
Pattern regex = Pattern.compile(".*hello\\sworld.*);
```

Comment: Keep in mind that at least that first wildcard needs to be reluctant for your code to work.